# very slow response from jQuery keyup function

Tags: jquery

I am stuck into an interesting problem. I have a table with 3 columns and some rows. Each rows are added with a click event that is supported by Drupal tablefield module which makes an ajax call to increase the number of rows. In 2 columns it accepts numeric data and my jQuery code does the calculation in third column. But as the rows increases the keyup functions gets super slow but for the first few rows it works fine. Below is my jQuery code snippets:

```
$('#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund input.tablefield-col-1, #edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund input.tablefield-col-2').keyup(function(index,value){
    var sum_cell_column;
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');          
    var Row = $tr.index();
    var cell_value1=Number($('#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund input#tablefield_0_cell_'+Row+'_1').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var cell_value2=Number($('#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund input#tablefield_0_cell_'+Row+'_2').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    sum_cell_column =(cell_value1+cell_value2);
    $('#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund input#tablefield_0_cell_'+Row+'_3').val(sum_cell_column).formatCurrency();
});
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try `$('#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund').on('keyup','.tablefield-col-1, .tablefield-col-2').keyup(function (e) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var cell_value1 = Number($tr.find('.tablefield-col-1').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    var cell_value2 = Number($tr.find('.tablefield-col-2').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    var sum_cell_column = (cell_value1 + cell_value2);
    $tr.find('.tablefield-col-3').val(sum_cell_column).formatCurrency();
});`

Comment: it is a much cleaner version and also assumes that the sum input field has a class `tablefield-col-3`

Comment: how many rows do you have, and what exactly do you mean by "super slow"?

Comment: one main problem is the selector `#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund  input#tablefield_0_cell_'+Row+'_3'`, if you have an id then there is no need to append any other rules with it... it should be as simple as `#tablefield_0_cell_'+Row+'_3'`

Comment: How many rows are we talking about when it starts visibly slowing down?

Comment: @i-- after adding more than 9 rows it starts to slow down

Comment: No idea, is there a lot of code over and under it? If not, might be helpful to post that too. Could be some issue(s) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would benefit from the `on` method, so that you are not attaching so many listeners. Using `on` with a filter on the input tag will mean that only one event listener will be attached.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Signature:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Sample:

```
  $('#edit-field-project-resrc-budget-fund').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $tr = $this.closest('tr'),
        row = $tr.index();  

    var makeId = function(index, pos) {
      return 'tablefield_0_cell_' + index + '_' + pos;
    };

    var cell_value1=Number($('#'+ makeId(row, 1))
                           .val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var cell_value2=Number($('#'+ makeId(row, 2))
                           .val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var sum_cell_column =(cell_value1+cell_value2);

    $('#'+ makeId(row, 3))
      .val(sum_cell_column).formatCurrency();
  });
```

Demo:

Here is a JSBin demonstrating this.  Use the button to create many rows and notice the performance is fine.

http://jsbin.com/oMEKaKu/4/

Comment: what a clear explanation thank you so much it works like a charm very appreciated !